STM32H750 isochronous missing packets
I am making a USB HS open-source sound card using STM32H750. Essentially, I got the USB audio class template and modified it to USB audio class 2. And, I have several problems with packets being skipped.
In a “good” USB port, everything is fine, but when something like a mouse is plugged into the hub it seems like the PC is sending multiple packets per SOF, and some of these packets are being ignored, even when USBD_AUDIO_DataOut code is minimal — STM32 sees only one packet per SOF and then the “missing” packets without anything during the next 2-3 SOFs. USBD_AUDIO_IsoOutIncomplete starts being called, and I am not sure what to do inside it beside preparing for the next receive. USB DMA helped, but did not solve the problem. Cache is disabled globally, all RAM memory is in DMA-enabled RAM.

USBD_AUDIO_IsoOutIncomplete is always called with epnum 0. Is it normal?

Why am I missing packets? Is it because the USB core is too slow? How do I speed it up?

If it is an internal USB buffer problem (if there is one), how do I increase it?


The descriptor says the maximum size of isochronous data out packet of 1024, but I always receive packets of size 48 at 48 kHz - 48000 samples / (8000 SOF/sec) * 2 channels * 4 bytes.

What type of USB analyzer do you use to work on this project?

@Ale..chenski USBlyzer. Unfortunately, it only shows URBs (requests from the OS to the USB chip) and not packets themselves. I am waiting for a "Usb sniffer", it is literally called that, it's an open source github project. What am I doing to check the packets is increasing a counter each SOF and writing to the counter position each dataOut event. I see 0s regularly and two packets sent at the same time - the array element is increased twice. On linux, OS sends 6-7 packages apparenlty (I see only one) and then 0s for 6-7 SOFs.

You should realize that in HS mode (480Mbps) the SOF change its number only every 8 micro-frames. All 8 uSOFs have the same frame number.

@Ale..chenski I am just increasing a counter in a SOF callback, which is called at 8kHz - checked on an oscilloscope by toggling a pin each callback.
